# On the theorem "$3$ is everywhere"

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, asymptotics, recreational-mathematics

In [this Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfEiJJGv4CE) it is stated that "almost all natural numbers have the digit $3$ in their decimal representation", and a proof of this fact is proposed.
A sketch of the proof follows:

Denote by $D_3$ the set of natural numbers having a digit $3$ in their decimal representation. For all $n \ge 1$, denote by
$$f(n) = | D_3 \cap \{ 1, \dots , n\} |$$
it is proved that for all $n$
$$f(10^n) = 10^n- 9^n $$
holds (and this is quite clear), hence
$$\lim_{n \to + \infty} \frac{f(10^n)}{10^n} = 1$$
and this concludes the proof in the video.

Now, this proof is clear and evident to me, but I think that it is incomplete, since we should prove that

> $$\lim_{n \to + \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n} = 1$$

while this is not proved in the video. So my question is: how to prove this?

EDIT: Obviously, if the limit exists, then it is equal to $1$: so I am asking how to show that the last limit actually exists.

Comment: If the limit exists, then $\lim_{n \to + \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n} =\lim_{n \to + \infty} \frac{f(10^n)}{10^n}$ and $(9/10)^n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Showing that the limit exists is another story though.

Comment: @Surb I totally agree with you, but we should prove that the limit exists.

Comment: I don't think you need to prove $\;\lim\frac{f(n)}n\;$ exists: with the existence of the given limit is enough as this shows in decimal notation (i.e. power of $\;10\,$...!), as you extend the number of digits in the limit you get one .

Comment: @Joanpemo of course you need to show that the limit exists. Look at $(-1)^n$, if you only look at the subsequence of even $n$ you might be convinced that it converges...

Comment: @s.harp Thank you. If you want to find out the limit of $\;f(n)/n\;$ then of course you could first prove it exists at all. I'm not saying that you can deduce the existence of a limit from the existence of the limit of a subsequence. IF you read my comment I'm saying that I think that it is enough to prove the existence of the limit of $\;f(10^n)/10^n\;$ in order to solve the ORIGINAL PROBLEM. I don't care about the limit of $\;f(n)/n\;$ ...In fact, I'm not even sure whether this last limit exists.

Comment: @Joanpemo the problem is actually how to show that $\lim_n f(n)/n=1$, not just the special case where $n$ is a power of $10$. And the limit definitely exists.

Comment: @s.harp For the first one I disagree, but of course I could be wrong. I think the important case here is the sequence $\;\left\{\frac{f(10^n)}{10^n}\right\}\;$ . About the exists of the limit of $\;f(n)/n\;$ I can't say nothing but express my doubts about its existence. May I ask how are you so sure it exists? If you can prove it then all is solved as the limit of the powers of ten subsequence and the whole sequence's are thus the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that proving $\lim_{n \to + \infty} \frac{f(10^n)}{10^n} = 1$ is not enough.  I can define $g(n)=n$ if $n=10^k$ and $g(n)=0$ otherwise.  I then have $\lim_{n \to + \infty} \frac{g(10^n)}{10^n} = 1$ but $\lim_{n \to + \infty} \frac{g(n)}{n}$  does not exist.  We have shown that if $\lim_{n \to + \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n}$ exists, it is $1$, so all we need now is that it exists.  We can use the same argument.  Define $h(n)=n-f(n)$ as the number of numbers less than $n$ that are missing $3$.  They show $h(10^n)=9^n$.  $h(n)$ is monotonically increasing as when you go from $n$ to $n+1$ you either add $1$ or $0$ to $h$.  Now for any $k$, let $m=\lfloor \log_{10}k \rfloor$ so that $10^m$ is the power of $10$ just below $k$.  $\frac {f(k)}k =1-\frac {h(k)}k \gt 1-\frac {9^{m+1}}{10^m}\to 1$

Comment: The key fact I was missing was that $h$ is monotonically increasing. Thanks for having pointed that out.

Comment: @Crostul:  My earlier argument failed for the reason you said.  I needed to use $h$ so I could invoke the fact that $9^{m+1}$ becomes small compared to $10^m$

Comment: A slight modification to this argument should show that almost all natural numbers contain a fixed substring of any length, no? So almost all natural numbers contain a binary representation of "Hamlet".

Comment: @Mr.Chip:  You are correct.  Good point.